# Killed buffer still shown by an earlier Ctrl-x Ctrl-b

Tags: buffers, buffer-list

I found that a killed buffer is still shown by a buffer created earlier by `C-x C-b`. How can we get the up-to-date buffer list?

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>g</kbd> calls `revert-buffer`.
Not updating each time is by design and can be seen as an advantage.

Comment: thanks. M-g or C-g? What advantage is it?

Comment: The shortcut is a plain `g`.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable automatic updating of the buffer list by adding to your ~/.emacs: `(add-hook 'Buffer-menu-mode-hook 'auto-revert-mode)`